# Mask an array by the index given from other array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, mask

I have the following arrays:

```
a = [10, 31, 30, 11, 17, 12, 22, 25, 85, 17, 21, 43]
b = [0, 1, 4, 6]
```

I want to mask `a` based on the index given by array `b`. That means getting:

```
c = [True, True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Comment: Look into `np.arange` and `np.in1d` funcs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [524]: a=np.array([10, 31, 30, 11, 17, 12, 22, 25, 85, 17, 21, 43])
In [525]: b=np.array([0, 1, 4, 6])
```

To make a boolean `c` that is True at the `b` indices, just use:

```
In [526]: c=np.zeros(a.shape, bool)
In [527]: c[b]=True

In [528]: c
Out[528]: 
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Then you can select the values of `a` with:

```
In [529]: a[c]
Out[529]: array([10, 31, 17, 22])
```

but you could just as well select them with `b`:

```
In [530]: a[b]
Out[530]: array([10, 31, 17, 22])
```

but `c` is better for removing those, `a[~c]`.  `np.delete(a,b)` does the same thing.

Other array methods of generating `c` are

```
np.in1d(np.arange(a.shape[0]),b)
np.any(np.arange(a.shape[0])==b[:,None],0)
```

And since I was just discussing masked arrays in another question, I could do the same here:

```
In [542]: np.ma.MaskedArray(a,c)
Out[542]: 
masked_array(data = [-- -- 30 11 -- 12 -- 25 85 17 21 43],
             mask = [ True  True False False  True False  True False False False False False],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: Am I doing something wrong or does this not work with 2D arrays?

Comment: @Yannic, I don't know what you doing or trying to do.  But the masking that I demonstrated is easiest with 1d arrays.  Somethings are different when working with 2+d arrays.  If you are primarily trying to 'index', it would be a good idea to read the basic numpy documentation on the subject.  It's a powerful concept, but it does take time to learn.

Comment: I found the solution here: https://zhangresearch.org/post/numpy-unravel-index/
You need to use "fancy indexing". First extract the column and row indices as separate lists like this: rows=coords[:,0] and cols=coords[:,1]. After that you can use arr[rows, cols] to get or modify multiple values in a 2d-array at once.

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.in1d` on a new array created with `np.arange` from the length of `a`:

```
>>> a = [10, 31, 30, 11, 17, 12, 22, 25, 85, 17, 21, 43]
>>> b = [0, 1, 4, 6]
>>> a = np.array(a)
>>> b = np.array(b)
>>> np.in1d(np.arange(len(a)), b)
array([ True,  True, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, False,
       False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 2):

It will be something like this:

```
c = []
for i, v in enumerate(a):
    mask = True if i in b else False
    c.append(mask)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to return 'c' with the unmasked values of 'a' without changing its size?

Comment: You could append to `c` if `False` a `tuple` like `(False, v)` and should be it. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

```
res = [False] * len(a)
for idx in b:
    res[idx] = True
```

or

```
[idx in b for idx in range(len(a))]
```

Answer (score 0):

## For anyone who wants to use this for 2D-arrays or N-dimensional arrays:

I found the solution here: https://zhangresearch.org/post/numpy-unravel-index

### In case the link goes dead some time in the future here is the approach:

You have to use "fancy indexing"

```
>>> a = np.arange(20).reshape(4, 5)
>>> print(a)
[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8  9]
 [10 11 12 13 14]
 [15 16 17 18 19]]
>>> b = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 3], [1, 1], [2, 2]])
>>> print(b)
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 3]
 [1 1]
 [2 2]]
>>> b_x = b[:, 0]
>>> b_y = b[:, 1]
>>> print(b_x)
[0 0 0 1 2]
>>> print(b_y)
[0 1 3 1 2]

>>> print(a[b_x, b_y])
[ 0  1  3  6 12]
```